# How to find the number of returned objects from an Actionscript getter function?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, for-loop, label, vbox

In my Flex project, I have a service function getItems() that returns me a collection/array of Item objects.

The function runs an SQL statement like SELECT * FROM table. I therefore do not want to use a SELECT COUNT SQL statement.

I know that if I use a Flex spark:DataGrid, I can easily get the length of the datagrid to know the number of rows (which in my case, would be the number of objects returned by my getItems() function). However, I am using an mx:AdvancedDataGrid and it is not possible to get the length by the same means as with the spark:DataGrid.

Actually, I need to dynamically create a set of labels with text={ItemName}. Using a Vbox and a for loop, I am able to create a list of labels. At the moment, I have a random number for the delimiter in my for loop. I just need to get the number of objects returned by my getItems() function. I can then put that number in the for loop and the job is done.

At least, this is how I plan to do this task.

Is there a better way to do this?

PS: I have Googled extensively, but I could not find any working examples for what I want to do.

Suggestions are welcome and StackOverflow is fabulous!

[EDIT] I eventually used an mx:Repeater to do the task described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this:

```
private function getItemsResultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
{
    var items:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
    items = event.result as ArrayCollection;

    trace(items.length);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This saved me from calling the getItems() function again.

Comment: However, I still consume some physical memory by creating an ArrayCollection. Is there a way to obtain the length of the getItemsResult.lastResult, for example? I could not get the .length for the lastResult property from the Content Assist menu.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something? Does this work for you?

```
var list:IList = getItems();
trace(list.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

ArrayCollection has a length attribute inherited from ListCollectionView.  Is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
getItemsResult.lastResult.length
```

or

```
(getItemsResult.lastResult as ArrayCollection).length
```

or

```
ArrayCollection(getItemsResult.lastResult).length
```

All are essentially the same.

Comment: The first one does not work. I am using Flash Builder for PHP 4.5 (Flex 4) and I do not get the .length property for the lastResult property of getItemsResult.

Which version of the Flex SDK are you using?

Comment: Context assist might not be able to detect the property, because at compile time, you dont really know what getItemsResult.lastResult is going to be. It will be whatever your service sends back. In this case, since you know it will be ArrayCollection, the first one will work at runtime, and you should not get a compile error. Are you getting a runtime error? If so, post the error.

Comment: Thank you for the input. 

For everybody having the same question: I ended up using an mx:Repeater to do the job.